# Can't use && or <@ on arrays operators when working with javax.persistence queries

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts(
    postid SERIAL NOT NULL,
    owner SERIAL NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    message VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    continent VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    country VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    state VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    languages VARCHAR(100)[] NOT NULL,
    properties varchar(100) ARRAY NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (postid),
    FOREIGN KEY (owner) REFERENCES users(userid) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I have *org.javax.persistence version 1.0.0.Final*

Basically what I'm trying to do is run the following queries using an entity manager with the type javax.persistence.Query

```
final Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT postid FROM posts WHERE :properties <@ cast(properties as text[])");
query.setParameter("properties",propAux);
```

The error that I am getting is the following: *org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: cannot cast type bytea to text[]
Position: 44*

I don't know if my hibernate version is relevant but it's 5.1.4.Final (I don't think it is though, note that I'm using the entityManager of javax.persistence instead of org.hibernate)
If it is relevant, however, my hibernate dialect is: *org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL92Dialect*

I tried to fix it like this:

```
final Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT postid FROM posts WHERE :country = country AND cast(:properties as text[]) <@ cast(properties as text[])");
                    query.setParameter("properties", new TypedParameterValue(StringArrayType.INSTANCE,propAux));
```

Afterwards I got the following error:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003
```

The query that is being generated by hibernate is:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE country = ? AND cast(? as text[]) <@ cast(properties as text[]) limit ?
```

I tried it in psql filling in the ?'s and it worked. But the problem is I don't know what my code is filling them with exactly. That's probably causing the issue but I don't know.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This does not look like an error in JPA/hibernate, but like an error coming directly from postgres. Does the query work when you directly connect to the database (e.g. via `psql`) and execute it?

Comment: I'm migrating my project to hibernate. I used to have this query instead:
```jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE ? <@ properties", new Object[] { propAux }, POST_ROW_MAPPER)``` and it'd work

Comment: That does not answer my question though...

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you

Comment: Yes. I just tried the query: ```SELECT postid FROM posts WHERE '{"property"}' <@ cast(properties as text[])``` and it worked.

Comment: This is not the same as the native query in the question though. I would suggest to use the working query 1:1 in Java.

Comment: What's different about this query?

Comment: Tbh, I am not entirely sure. You can configure hibernate to log all queries and take a look what hibernate generates.

Comment: That is  a good idea! Thanks

Comment: For some reason, the query being generated is the following: ```SELECT * FROM posts WHERE country = ? AND cast(? as text[]) <@ properties limit ?``` and when I run it in psql it doesn't work. It says that <@ doesn't work with those array types. However when I replace that query for ```SELECT * FROM posts WHERE country = ? AND cast(? as text[]) <@ cast(properties as text[]) limit ?``` it does work. I just don't know how to make the change so createNativeQuery creates it that way.

Comment: You may want to [edit] the post and add that bit of information.

Comment: I will look into it some more then edit it

Comment: If you find the solution yourself, please remember that you can [self-answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Okay managed to change it now the query that is being executed is:```SELECT * FROM posts WHERE country = ? AND cast(? as text[]) <@ cast(properties as text[]) limit ?
 ```  and the error is no longer SQL grammar and instead is: ```caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 2003``` I have no idea what causes this so I'm going to update it now.

Comment: There is a [plug-and-play library for adding array types](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-array-contributor/1.2), but it requires Hibernate 5.2. However there are some incompatibilities when migrating from 5.1 to 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a custom type like the one from the Hibernate-Types project if you want to use the `TypedValue` approach: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Passing in a string and casting that then to an array is an option as well though like you figured.